# My custom Form Type Template is ignored when rendering form

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I created a custom field type class `BootstrapToggleType extends AbstractType` which is child of `CheckboxType` I also prefixed it just in case as follows

```php
public function getBlockPrefix(): string
{
    return 'bootstrap_toggle';
}
```

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $config = $form->getParent()->get($form->getName())->getConfig();
            $options = $config->getOptions();
            $defaultDataOptions = $this->_bootstrapToggleDataDefaults;

            $form->getParent()->add($form->getName(), CheckboxType::class, array_replace_recursive($options, [
                'attr' => $defaultDataOptions,
            ]))
            ;
        });
    }
```

I added custom form theme to twig.yaml `form_themes: ['Form/custom_types.html.twig', 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']` and created mentioned file with following code

```
{% block bootstrap_toggle_row %}
    {% for child in form.children if not child.rendered %}
        <div class="my-custom-wrapper">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(child) }}
                {{ form_widget(child) }}
                {{ form_help(child) }}
                {{ form_errors(child) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

However the field is rendered using standard theme ignoring `bootstrap_toggle_row` What am I doing wrong?

The problem is basically with this part of code `$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {` . However I need to use such construction to create a field using name provided by `FormType` object `$builder->add('is_published', BootstrapToggleType::class)`

if I change that part of code to something like that

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addChild('testName', CheckboxType::class);
}
```

my custom template is rendered correctly.

**added**

Because I re-added another child I have to provide it's correct block prefix.

```
$form->getParent()->add($form->getName(), CheckboxType::class, array_replace_recursive($options, [
                'attr' => $defaultDataOptions,
                'block_prefix' => 'bootstrap_toggle'
            ]));
```

Then in my custom template I need to reffer directly to the `form` variable as a single child, not an array. So instead of looping over children

```
{% for child in form.children if not child.rendered %}
```

just direct call

```
{{ form_label(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_help(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

Now it works.

Comment: `dump` your form and check the block prefixes of your form. also please show how you actually render your form (the part with `form_start(...)`)

Comment: @Jakumi thanks for the idea of dumping form object. You were right. There was a `checkbox` block prefix added, because I re-added that field as simple checkbox. 
I updated my post with solution I figured out.